# Adding a Foreign Key referencing AspNetUser when creating a table using Code First - MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a Visual Studios MVC5 Web application and I am trying to reference the id from AspNetUser table as a foreign key.

I am creating a new table :

```
public class Patient
{
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string HCN { get; set; }
    public string GP { get; set; }
    public string MedHis { get; set; }
    public string Medication { get; set; }
    public string CurrentPrescription { get; set; }
    public string PresentRX { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser UserId { get; set; }
}
```

My `Patient` config class :

```
public class PatientConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Patient>
{
    public PatientConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Patient");

        Property(x => x.PatientId).HasColumnName("IntId");
        HasKey(x => x.PatientId);

        Property(x => x.HCN).HasColumnName("strHCN");
        Property(x => x.GP).HasColumnName("strGP");
        Property(x => x.MedHis).HasColumnName("strMedHis");
        Property(x => x.Medication).HasColumnName("strMedication");

        Property(x => x.CurrentPrescription).HasColumnName("strCurrentPrescription");

        Property(x => x.PresentRX).HasColumnName("strPresentRX");
        Property(x => x.UserId).HasColumnName("intUserId");
    }
}
```

Firstly I was getting the error

> Must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as a parameter

underneath the `UserId` property so I removed it

```
Property(x=> x.UserId).HasColumnName("intUserId");
```

When I tried to add the migration I got the following error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'UserId' on type 'ModelTest.Models.Patient' is not valid. The foreign key name 'UserId' was not found on the dependent type 'ModelTest.Models.Patient'. The Name value should be a comma separated list of foreign key property names.

I don't understand how the `UserId` cannot be found, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This works like any other relationship. There's nothing special about `ApplicationUser`. It seems you just don't really understand how to set up Entity Framework relationships in the first place.

If you *don't* care about having an explicit foreign key property that you can access in your application, then all you need to add to your entity is:

```
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

That will cause Entity Framework to generate an *implicit* foreign key on your entity's table, but you won't be able to access this value directly in your application. `User` will be a full instance of `ApplicationUser`.

If you *do* want access to the foreign key property directly, then you need something like:

```
[ForeignKey("User")]
public string UserId { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

Now, there's an actual property on the entity to hold the foreign key value, in addition to the navigation property that allows you to access the appropriate `ApplicationUser` instance.

While Entity Framework should actually be able to figure out that `UserId` is the foreign key for the `User` navigation property on its own by convention, I find it better to always be explicit by using the `ForeignKey` attribute.

Also, notice that the type for `UserId` is `string`. This the type `IdentityUser` uses by default for the primary key. You can change that if you like, but if you just use the standard deployment, then it'll be a `string` rather than something like `int`, which you seem to have assumed it would be in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
[ForeignKey("User")]<br/>
public string UserId { get; set; }<br/>
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

When I add the above lines to the class, and then migrate and update the DB,
 I get ApplicationUser Table created !